# Is the following property for positive random variables fulfilled in general?

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a continuous random variable $X$, defined on the interval $[0, \infty)$, which has density $f(x)$ and a finite expectation and variance.

I am wondering whether the following is true in general:

Take any value $\alpha > 0$, and let

$x_1 := \mathbb{E}(X|X \leq \alpha)$, while

$x_2 := \mathbb{E}(X|X > \alpha)$.

Will a new, discrete random variable $\tilde{X}$, where
$\tilde{X} = x_1$ with probability $F(\alpha)$, and $\tilde{X} = x_2$ with probability $1-F(\alpha)$, always have a lower variance than $X$?

I have checked that this property is true for the uniform distribution. Formally, it is straightforward to see that the property is fulfilled if for all $\alpha > 0$,

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 f(x)dx \geq \frac{\left(\int_0^\alpha x f(x) dx\right)^2}{F(\alpha)} + \frac{\left(\int_\alpha^\infty f(x) dx\right)^2}{1-F(\alpha)}$.

Using Jensen's inequality, a sufficient condition for the above is that

$\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} x f(x)dx\right)^2 \geq \frac{\left(\int_0^\alpha x f(x) dx\right)^2}{F(\alpha)} + \frac{\left(\int_\alpha^\infty f(x) dx\right)^2}{1-F(\alpha)}$.

However, I am not really sure where to go from there. The integral in the LHS can still be split up into the range $0$ to $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ to $\infty$, but doesn't seem to help me much.

Maybe the property is not true in general, after all?

Any input is appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The property does hold, in great generality.

Let $X$ denote any (integrable) real valued random variable and $a$ some real number such that $A=[X\leqslant a]$ and $A^c=[X\gt a]$ both have positive probability. Let $X_a$ denote any random variable such that $X_a=E[X\mid A]$ with probability $P[A]$ and $X_a=E[X\mid A^c]$ with probability $P[A^c]=1-P[A]$. Then $E[X_a]=E[X]$ and 
$$
E[X_a^2]=E[X:A]^2P[A]^{-1}+E[X:A^c]^2P[A^c]^{-1}.
$$
For every event $B$, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to $(X\mathbf 1_B)\cdot\mathbf 1_B$ yields
$$
E[X:B]^2=E[(X\mathbf 1_B)\cdot\mathbf 1_B]^2\leqslant E[(X\mathbf 1_B)^2]E[\mathbf 1_B^2]=E[X^2:B]P[B],
$$
hence, for every event $B$ with positive probability,
$$
E[X:B]^2P[B]^{-1}\leqslant E[X^2:B].
$$
Applying this to $B=A$ and to $B=A^c$ and summing the resulting upper bounds yields
$$
E[X_a^2]\leqslant E[X^2:A]+E[X^2:A^c]=E[X^2].
$$
Finally, since $E[X_a]=E[X]$,

> $$\mathrm{var}(X_a)\leqslant\mathrm{var}(X).$$

Although the above fully proves the desired result, it may help to put it in a more general context. Let $\mathcal A=\{\varnothing,A,A^c,\Omega\}$ denote the sigma-algebra generated by $A$, then $Y=E[X\mid\mathcal A]$ is an example of a random variable $X_a$, since $Y=E[X\mid A]\mathbf 1_A+E[X\mid A^c]\mathbf 1_{A^c}$. It happens that, for every sigma-algebra $\mathcal G$, $Z=E[X\mid\mathcal G]$ is such that $E[Z]=E[X]$ and $Z^2\leqslant E[X^2\mid\mathcal G]$. Integrating the last inequality (called conditional Cauchy-Schwarz inequality), one gets $E[Z^2]\leqslant E[E[X^2\mid\mathcal G]]=E[X^2]$. Thus, $E[Z]=E[X]$ and $E[Z^2]\leqslant E[X^2]$, which proves the general result that 
$$
\mathrm{var}(E[X\mid\mathcal G])\leqslant\mathrm{var}(X).
$$

Comment: No density needed. If X is integrable but not square integrable the LHS is finite and the RHS is infinite hence the inequality holds. If X is not integrable, none of these conditional expectations make any sense anyway.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed reply. I'll make sure to go through the steps (starting from Cauchy-Schwarz) carefully.

Comment: Coming to think of it, the property seems a bit strange though. In essence, I believe it implies that one can split up a random variable into smaller and smaller sub-portions, define a new, discrete random variable out of those, and reduce its variance. However, for infinitely many sub-portions, we end up with the original distribution (and hence, original variance) again. Where is the fallacy here?

Comment: No fallacy. The more refined the partition is, the largest the variance is. Extreme low: partition $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$, then $Z=E[X]$ hence the variance of $Z$ is zero. Extreme high: $\mathcal G=\mathcal F$ (the most refined possible partition), then $Z=X$ hence the variance of $Z$ is the variance of $X$.

Comment: I am missing a proper background in probability theory, so my understanding is on a naïve level, but are you essentially saying that splitting up a distribution into $N \geq 1$ subintervals and making a new discrete random variable out of it (which takes on the $N$ different expectations of each subinterval, with corresponding probability), has a variance that is monotonically increasing in $N$ (given that when going from $N$ to $N+1$, we do not change the old "boundaries")?

Comment: Yes. In other words, to refine a partition can only increase the variance. One may think of $X$ itself as corresponding to the *finest* partition of all (and of the constant $E[X]$ as corresponding to the *coarsest* one).

Comment: Great, I think I understand it now. That's a very nice result. I'll accept your answer directly - thanks a lot for helping out!